# During notice period, my manager wants me to document everything and bring juniors to my level

Tags: notice-period, resignation

I am in my notice period. I think that I should just wrap things up and let my replacement, who should be an expert like me, take over what I do.

My main tasks are quite common for my area of expertise, but I have been asked to document everything in extreme detail so that management and other non-expert staff could easily understand what I did. This would be low-level documentation meant to be understandable by random project managers.

Moreover, I am supposed to teach everything I know to junior staff so that they can replicate what I have been doing.

I feel like an idiot, as my manager previously didn't give me the opportunity of teaching and training my own team. I was not valued, and now they want to take everything from me before I walk out, so that they can say that what I did was nothing special.

Q: are there reasonable limitations to how much information I should share, and should I even teach junior staff during notice?

Comment: If not knowledge transfer, what did you think the notice period was for?

Comment: If you don't like it you can just leave without giving notice. This is called "burning bridges" but you seem really upset that you have to do what your manager tells you for 2 more whole weeks.

Comment: Every time I've transferred jobs, my notice period was documentation.  Same goes for my colleagues.  You should not be upset about this, this is very standard, especially in smaller companies.  In bigger companies, this might not be that common.  So gut up and just DO IT!

Comment: I don't think it's worth a separate answer here (there's plenty of great answers), but let me just add one thing: take it as an opportunity. For one, to leave a good impression of yourself. Two, improve your writing and teaching skills. If you want to grow as a software developer, both of these skills are essential, and any opportunity you have to improve them *while being paid for all your work* should be exploited for all its worth. When I was doing my last handover, I went crazy with both, and subsequently improved my worth considerably. Software development is more about people than code.

Comment: Push back on the dcoumentation.  You **should** do documentation, but you may be able to provide a more valuable service to the by writing the *right* documentation.  They're asking for ultra-low level documentation because that's what they believe is the most useful documentation you can provide.  If you can convince them that higher level documentation is more valuable, then you make their lives better and make your life more fun!  If not, well, its the documentation they're paying you for.

Comment: It's just the way things are, and always have been.  Thag The Caveman: "Ug, me quit go other job two weeks"  Thag's boss: "Ug, sorry see you go. Write down everything know on cave wall. Make sure Dave know make fire before go."

Comment: If you have been in the job for several months or even multiple years, it is unlikely that you'll be able to bring a new employee to your level in a month. But the only professional conduct from your side would be to try your best to achieve it anyway. It would probably be better to let the new employee write the documentation under your guidance, but that is not necessarily your decision to make.

Comment: @AE perhaps to give the company a chance to hire someone who already has enough experience?

Comment: OP is not saying how long the notice period is. In some countries/positions it may be 1 month, in others 2 weeks or maybe just 1 week. Anyway who is going to judge the documentation afterwards to ensure you have included "everything you know"? It's rather common that documentation always misses something and so there is a chance that some people may be unhappy with it to some degree in any case.

Comment: @coderworks Yeah, that works too. :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think most of the answers are missing the essence of your dilemma.

You didn't have a great work environment and you felt slighted at the company, so naturally you found another job.

Now that you are leaving they seem to value what you did more.  You may think your task are simple but your management may be freaking out.  So what right?

First they can ask you to do whatever you want during your notice period.  You can refuse most or all that don't have to do with your current job.

You may think you want to stick it to the company but you are also sticking it to your co-workers a bit too.  They may have trouble functioning, they might have to work extra, maybe they don't but they remember you left in a hostile manner.  So even if you don't want anything to do with this company for the rest of your life you now have 20-30 people in your industry that view you as a black cloud.   So step one is play nice and have a good attitude your last few weeks since people will remember those the most.

Next have a talk with your manager and be honest about what you can get done.  For example you mention teaching your coworkers to train them to your level.  I personally see issues with this.  I have been in tech for 20 years and had 40+ guys reporting to me at a time.  I don't ever remember asking one to train their replacement when they gave notice.  You are not a trainer or teacher of developers and if you were you would get paid more.

Asking you to document what you do is fine.  If you want to do a half-ass job, whatever.  Just have a good attitude about it and don't act like you are half-assing it.   Any level headed tech manager worried about an employee leaving with knowledge first has already failed their job and second they would have someone shadow you do specific things - note I said shadow not have you train them.  That puts the onus of when things get done on the manager not you.  No manager should trust that you will get this stuff done when you are on notice so they should be managing what is being transferred.  The same reason you wanted to leave is probably the same reason they are mismanaging this.

Also don't let your management or HR rile you up.  If they want to act like you are being hard to deal with just smile and do your job.  It is a tough situation leaving a company that has management issues.  Don't focus on getting everything done.  Let them manage that.  Offer to be available after notice period (for a premium).  If they don't want to take you up on it, that is on them.  My gut tells me they will let their junior devs run around in circles for months.

Comment: I'm assuming "to my level" is hyperbole since most management knows what's possible and what isn't in a given time period even if they ask for more.. Your milage will vary.  Having had to pick up pieces after someone left without documenting their work, I can tell you that there is _always_ stuff worth passing along unless you really are a mindless cog.

Comment: +1 I quite like this answer, it gets to the essence of it from the OP's viewpoint in terms of his/her general dissatisfaction with the workplace. I had a manager downplay my skills and achievments and expect juniors to pick up my slack without losing a beat. In fact that company lost several clients after I left. The manager was an idiot, which is not as rare as you may think.

Comment: THANK YOU. My code is already documented. My domain knowledge is not, because for that you need a couple of degrees. But they want me to make sure that by removing the only domain expert they will lose nothing.

Comment: Great Answer, my only comment concerns the following: "Any level headed tech manager worried about an employee leaving with knowledge first has already failed their job" - In jobs I worked every employee leaving has some implicit knowledge that will go with them. Worrying about minimizing this is not management failure.

Comment: @Monoandle Of course they want to do that - wouldn't you? You should certainly spend your time working there (even if it is your last few weeks) doing whatever the company wants you to do...

Answer (score 210):

This is exactly what a notice period is for -- to transfer as much of your knowledge about the work as possible to other people so the company doesn't lose it. They aren't "taking from you" anything except what is theirs because they paid you for it.

It's not about you, it's about the business. Stop sulking and cooperate. As others have pointed out, you're still being paid to do so.

Comment: Doesn't documentation damage me? I spend lots of time improving myself, making mistakes and learning from them: if I just give away everything I know, am I not losing precious professional capital?

Comment: Documenting things for the company in no way damages you; it just keeps your departure from damaging them more than it must. So you help them get better -- so what? If you're on your way out they aren't your competition, and even if you weren't leaving this is a positive-sum game and trying to hoard info hurts you more than it hurts anyone else.

Comment: @Monoandale, believe it or not, your employer employs you to provide value to their business, not to improve yourself and develop your "precious professional capital". I advise you to adjust your attitude if you want to succeed in the workplace in the long term. Being directed to spend your notice period documenting and transferring knowledge is absolutely normal and commonplace, I can't think of a time when I changed jobs and was *not* so directed. Until your notice period is over, you still work there, so act like a professional and follow these directions.

Comment: In fact teaching others is one of the best ways to solidify your own knowledge. And one of the better ways to demonstrate value to your employer.

Comment: @Monoandale It's actually not _your_ professional capital.  It's the employer's.  You take away certain skills you learned in this job, they take away the work that you did.  To hand over is a win-win, not a zero sum game.

Comment: @Monoandale Furthermore, *they are paying you to do this.*

Comment: You don't need to give everything you have learned to the company. I discovered many time management and multi-tasking skills, shortcuts and techniques that greatly improved my efficiency over the years. I never give those to anyone, they give me an edge. All that is required is you give everything directly related to your work, no more, no less. Perhaps that is the professional capital mentioned?

Comment: Your "professional capital" will be greatly diminished by a reference that notes you hoarded knowledge while essentially refusing to do your job, and not diminished at all by one that notes your professional attitude at all times. And if you work in an actual professional field, you will find that the working world is a small place - you will have to deal in the future with people who will remember how you behave right now. You probably want them to remember you for the right reasons.

Comment: @Monoandale Spreading knowledge adds value to the people around you. It's a great way to stick out of the crowd in a very positive way. Who do you think an employer values the most. The wizard who can do everything and keeps an aura of mystery around it, or the professional who can do everything and helps his/her colleagues to up to his/her own level? If you keep jealously guarding your bag of tricks, you'll find out that in the long run it's a loss for you.

Comment: @Monoandale: *"I just give away everything I know, am I not losing precious professional capital?"* And yet, you're asking people on Stack Exchange to share *their* professional capital with *you*? Take a lesson from this experience: Helping others only *enhances* you, it doesn't in any way take anything away from you.

Comment: @mono It is the first time I see a single comment provoke comments of 10 different top answerers on here. I hope they helped you

Comment: Thanks everybody, I appreciate your comments. T.J. Crowder: well said, you are right. Thanks all for your time.

Comment: If there's any task that is done on a recurring basis then the process should already have been documented by you. That's what "professionals" do. If you haven't done so then you have already lost your professional capital and have identified yourself as nothing more than a hack. I document all my repeatable tasks and yet it doesn't allow others to reach my skill level. So your concern is not valid. Plus, I don't want to do the same things over and over. The sooner I document the steps the sooner I can pass the tedious task off to someone else and move on to new things. It's called win-win.

Comment: @keshlam As he is leaving his job there is absolutely nothing to gain by demonstrating value to your employer at this point.

Comment: @NewWorld: He has references and reputation to lose.

Answer (score 149):

The best and most professional thing I have found to do is create a handover document. This would include step by step procedures on any tasks only you are familiar with (complete with screenshots if necessary), things like network diagrams of clients (depending on what your position is), any passwords that only you know etc,. Everything consolidated in to one document. Use working hours to make this.

As far as training juniors go that's up to the company if they will give you time for that. Usually you can just give them the handover doc and go through it with someone if need be.

You already have one foot out of the door, so some companies will try and squeeze the last ounce out of you that they can. However you're leaving so don't let any pressure get to you. Just do the professional thing and do what needs to be done with the focus on your work carrying on with the least disruption when you're gone.

Take your time and do a solid job of it.

Comment: I'd suggest on top of this (if your short on available time) you could also speak to the manager who is making these requests and suggest that they can have a handover document, or training for the staff - but that there isn't time for both and ask them to prioritize which they prefer.

Comment: Also make sure that as well as training and/or producing documentation, any actual work you are expected to do during the notice period is accounted for in your time and official priority list. Leaving or not, you are one person and you can't be expected to do two or three jobs well. If the notice period isn't long enough to cover everything that is not your problem. If push comes to shove, make sure any overtime is not unpaid overtime.

Comment: So very useful how people accept the answer that they want to hear, not the actual correct answer. @keshlam has the real answer below, but OP didn't want to hear it... so they accepted this... what a shame.

Comment: @SnakeDoc, the way I see it, both answers are almost same, except in this one, the reasoning is much more detailed.

Comment: @UnderDog this answer isn't the same at all really. It's advocating creating a document, then walking away. The OP has clearly been asked to train and work with a new hire... that's not just handing them some word doc. It also gives the feeling that the company is trying to pull something over on the OP by "squeez[ing] the last ounce out ... that they can"... which is just flat wrong. So, no, the two answers are not even close (evidenced by the huge disparity in upvotes between them).

Comment: The phrase " to transfer as much of your knowledge about the work as possible to other people" is same as squeezing the last ounce out. Just dont take it all too literally. And the other answer doesnt necessarily advocate to train the new hire, it just asked to cooperate. Anyhow, I think the message is clear for OP. Either way, they are asking him to do the right thing

Comment: The answers are slightly different, mine advocates what is in my humble opinion best for the OP, the other champions the business. A good handover document negates the need for extensive training and will still be used in years to come as a base reference by people who haven't even started working there yet. I'm always going to advise what is best for the OP as I see it, not the company. I see nothing wrong with my solution, and it's what works for me. It focuses my knowledge of the job and is extremely useful to whoever takes over. It's far superior to any hurried training I might give.

Comment: @Kilisi the point of training is to give the new hire a chance to absorb things, think about them, then ask questions -- before the OP leaves for good. A "handoff doc" doesn't accomplish this - and it's unlikely one could encompass all of their knowledge into a single document. Simple things will be left out or forgotten, or won't be clear, etc. It's standard to train your replacement at most companies, and advocating not doing so when directly requested by the company, that is still paying you a salary, is wrong on many levels.

Comment: It's not rocket science, it's also an unhappy environment for the OP, this lets him/her concentrate on one task. As for simple things will be forgotten, that's rubbish. Documenting and procedural step by step will not forget the basics, I have written many manuals like this, in fact it helps make sure nothing is missed. You take your time and do it thoroughly. Not write a 2 page doc in an hour. You do it methodically and professionally if it takes 100 pages, then you do 100.

Comment: For training you use the document as a base reference and when you write it you assume you're writing for a not-too-bright beginner so there's little chance of misunderstanding. I'm not advocating refusing to train as you said, but realistically I've seen some awful training in my time, because most people are not teachers. I'd rather have a comprehensive doc to refer to.

Comment: @Kilisi The Op stated his employer directly tasked him with training the new person. If he/she then goes off on their own and makes some document, gives it to the new person then says "see ya!", that's a direct contradiction to his assigned tasks. His employer is still paying him, he has to do what they asked of him (especially since it's very reasonable). What you suggest is reasonable only if the OP had already prepared the document before this process started... but it's too late for that now. Like I said, training allows the new hire to ask questions and get answers. A document doesn't...

Comment: @Kilisi After reading your explanation, your answer makes all the way more sense. Writing a doc will definitely be helpful in years to come, moreover, if something was actually forgotten/missed, some one who is more senior can always pin point that, if they understand the part of it. Also, there is always a chance of forgetting something while you are giving the training, anyway. To make it worse, some people are not the smartest communicators but they can pen it down really well.

Comment: I am sorry I didn't write it more clearly: the documentation is not standard documentation for my code. That is already available, and explains people how to run everything to get what they want. What they want me to do is to write in details WHY certain decisions were made, and that is domain knowledge that only a peer would have. They want to be cheap about filling my role, and I am supposed to fill the gaps in the replacement's level.

Comment: @Monoandale That's perfectly fine. You're still an employee until your notice period ends. You still do whatever the people in charge ask you to do (within your job description, of course), and if they think your time is best spent preparing documentation, that's what you *must* do. As noted before, the whole point of the notice period *is* the handover (at least in software companies). Do your job. Don't push yourself into overtime or anything - just do your job, during your normal work hours. If they want to be cheap about your replacement, that's their problem and their decision.

Comment: @Monoandale A little late, but I haven't seen it noted anywhere: they want to know the *whys* for posterity.  At some point, someone is going to want to know why you did or didn't do something that you had a very good reason for.  That document is supposed to remind them why decisions were made so someone in a couple of years doesn't spend months implementing something just to find out why you in your forward-thinking *didn't do it in the first place*.  Sharing that kind of domain/project-specific knowledge does not "cheapen" your "precious professional capital."  It increases it.

Answer (score 57):

> are there reasonable limitations to how much information I should
>   share, and should I even teach junior staff during notice?

If you want to remain professional, and keep a good reputation intact, you work hard during your notice period - documenting, aiding in knowledge transfer, and helping in any way you can. That's what a notice period is for, and that's what you are getting paid to do.

You should be limited only by the hours you work, and your abilities.

If you don't care about your reputation, you could hold your breath and refuse to teach junior staff. Aside from vindictiveness, you have nothing to gain by taking this route. Perhaps you don't care.

A while back you asked if a company has a right to bad-mouth you and not recommend your services after you leave. Refusing to aid in the knowledge-transfer is one of those things that could matter. You don't want your last impression to be your worst.

Comment: Thanks Joe, very good point. I am letting resentment prevail here.

Comment: If you refuse to do the job duties assigned to you, including knowledge transfer, management would be justified in terminating you immediately for cause. This could have numerous negative impacts on you, such as immediate loss of unexercised stock options, and a possibility that the possibility that future employers verify your past employment they'll be informed of the terms of your departure.

Comment: Let's be clear here - he is not a trainer, he is a developer.  I trained developers for a few years and got paid much more than them.  Them shadowing is fine, asking questions is fine, but him training them up is not in his job realm.  If this were other intellectual jobs like general management no one would ever think he should be training them.

Comment: @blankip: False. He would still be expected to transfer his knowledge about this particular project/group/whatever. That's training, though not technical.

Answer (score 19):

You should put in your best efforts to provide them a 'hiccup-less' transfer. The reasons are in my humble opinion, some of them already mentioned above,

1. You do not want someone in the middle of the night to call you for some stupid stuff. Which can be taught in a minute.
2. You do not want to burn the bridges with the present company. Just because today you do not want to work here does not mean you would never want to work here.
3. This is in fact the best time to show your managers what they are losing.

When I left a small company where I had worked for a year, I made sure my juniors understood everything they needed to take care of, even the stuff I was doing R&D on that had no compulsion to be "handed over." In spite of that fact, my managers refused give me a raise. And when I found I had finished my 'KT' and still had time left over, I very politely asked whether they needed my help on anything else as the juniors were still learning to cope up.

They sure did.

Two months after I had joined my new company, my (ex) team lead called up and asked me whether I would like to rejoin my old company. I refused politely.

Answer (score 15):

If in two years of time, a prospective employer calls your former manager and asks him about your work, what do you prefer him saying?  "His work was good and he made sure to document it and train his replacements.  We are still using it productively." or "He refused documenting his work or handing it over in a proper manner, so we had to throw it all out and have it rewritten.  His employment ended up being a huge financial loss to us because of his attitude."?

Answer (score 9):

I think a lot of the other answerers don't get what you are saying. It is your job to document things to a level that someone of equivalent skill can use, it is not your job to spell everything out step by step for a novice because you can't possibly account for every unexpected eventuality.

Imagine that you were a chef in a fine restaurant, they can't expect you to bring a trainee upto your own level during a notice period. It is your responsibility to pass on business knowledge but it is an unrealistic expectation to handover a level of skill.

So what you need to do is manage your boss's expectations but also ensure that everything is thoroughly documented for someone with the appropriate skillset.

Comment: I'd add one more hypothetical to that: if OP learned these skills on the job (company paid him to learn it), then it is his responsibility to pass that knowledge on.  If he was hired because he already possessed that knowledge, it's less black-and-white though I would still err on the side of passing that knowledge on to the junior admins.

Comment: @user22217 The company paid him to learn it, doesn't mean he can teach it, that a junior is good enough to learn it too or that any of this is doable within the restricted timescale of a notice period.

Comment: @user22217 going back to the chef analogy. If he developed an amazing dish for the restaurant he should be passing on his secret recipe. But he can't be expected to turn a trainee into a michelin star chef in that time or even ensure that the trainee can cook that dish as well as a proper chef would.

Comment: So are you saying the answer to "are there reasonable limitations to how much information I should share, and should I even teach junior staff during notice?" is "whatever the people you're training are able to learn in the time available and yes", or are you saying the answer to that part of the question is "document your processes in a way that only someone of your own skill level can understand, and no"? Obviously the questioner can't do the assigned task if it's impossible, but there are different ways to respond to impossible requests.

Comment: I'd also note from " I was not valued, and now they want to take everything from me before I walk out, so that they can say that what I did was nothing special", that it seems the problem isn't that the OP fears the task is impossible (although I agree that would be a reasonable fear). The problem the OP has to deal with is fearing that it *is* possible and their role in fact can be filled by a junior trained up during the notice period. But there's a difference between handing over specific tasks and processes to a junior, and that junior taking on the whole role and showing you up.

Comment: @SteveJessop the problem with writing out steps for juniors is that when something deviates from what is expected they are lost. And when that happens the blame lands on the ex-senior for not foreseeing that out of all the infinate possibilities that could happen this precise one would occur.  Its an impossible task for any 'senior' role.  It seems to me that you are making the same assumptions as the company that is undervaluing the OP!

Comment: @SteveJessop the tasks (and level worker required) are dictated by what the company is trying to achieve. A company can't downgrade to a junior and get the same result just because it stamps it's feet.  If they choose to change structure they are also choosing a lesser result and it doesn't seem that in the OP's case they realise that.  And in any case, work to restructure is not a simple handover and would likely take longer than a notice period so again, not realistic.

Answer (score 9):

I don't see what your issue is. You're still an employee during your notice period, so it's still your job to do whatever reasonable tasks your manager assigns to you. You have been assigned the reasonable task of training other people to do something that you're an expert at.

Answer (score 8):

It's very human to only value something once it's lost (I bet there's a saying about that, but it doesn't come to mind). It certainly feels disappointing to be undervalued until you decide to quit, but you should expect that attitude (to some degree), otherwise you'll be setting yourself up for constant disappointment. Getting unfriendly and refuse to cooperate now will be quite unprofessional.

Instead transfer as much knowledge as you can, and try to prevent this situation to build up on your next job. A good indicator of "irreplaceable guy" issues is when you take vacation. If your tasks just pile up during that time (even urgent ones), you should tell your boss it's a problem and ask him if you should spend some time training your peers.

Also don't hesitate to tell your boss you can't handle your regular activities and transfer knowledge at the same time. If your boss is willing to dedicate enough time for training your peers, he's not the worst kind, believe me!

Personally, I go as far as leaving my personal e-mail to the team lead when I quit a project, and telling them I'm ready to answer questions should they be blocked. So far, I was contacted only once, to attend a project milestone celebration in a restaurant, and I must admit I take pride in always carefully preparing my departure. I believe you should, too.

Comment: I believe the song for this is "Don't it always seem to go/That you don't know what you got 'til it's gone/They paved paradise/And put up a parking lot" (Big Yellow Taxi/Joni Mitchell)